# Creating array of pointers to class object

Tags: c++, object, polymorphism, new-operator

Question:

Create an array of at least four pointers to Reader objects. Use the New operator to create at least four pointers to derived class objects and assign them to the array.

I'm not sure If I did it right or not.

Reader is the base class. John, David, Daniel, Mark are the derived class

```
int main(void)
{
     Reader *obj[4];

    obj[0] = new John();
    obj[1] = new David();
    obj[3] = new Daniel();
    obj[2] = new  Mark();

}
```

Would this be right???

Comment: Looks OK to me.  Add `return 0;` to the end though.

Comment: You've got a memory leak - you have to `delete` them later.

Comment: @Segey: Bad suggestion here. He has been specifically asked to use pointer array. This seems to be a homework kind of thing. I am all in favor of std::vector but not a good suggestion in this particular case.

Comment: Especially if he wants polymorphism.

Comment: @DeadMG do you think that polymorph pointers can not be stored in std::vector?

Comment: @Aamir Here the article from Andrew Koenig about C++ teaching drdobbs.com/blogs/cpp/229401490 where he explain why it is bad practice to use arrays for C++. Even if you doing homework - I see no reason to use array instead of std::vector and explain your decision to teacher.

Comment: @Sergey: Of course they can- but the *pointers* aren't what's dynamically allocated. It would be a better option to use an array of self-releasing pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is **correct**.

And as @sharptooth suggested, make a practice of `delete` on the allocated `obj[]`s. In C++ `new` allocates memory and `delete` deallocates.

Comment: in this case, `delete[] obj` is needed to correctly destruct and delete all objects and their pointers in the array

Comment: @eFloh delete [] obj is a terrible idea. It is wrong. 'obj' is a local variable. It is not allocated so you must not delete it. It will be destroyed when it goes out of scope. This destruction will do nothing because pointers don't have destructors.

However, obj[0-3] contain pointers to allocated objects. Those must be deleted with "delete obj[0];", etc.

Note that since this is incomplete code we cannot tell whether it is correct. Does Reader have a virtual destructor?

Comment: sorry, jumped up on @sharptooth proposal without noticing this. I mainly focused on the fact that arrays should be allocated using new[] and destroyed using the array variant of delete...